# Can't run client-server application without compiling it every time

Tags: c, sockets

I'm making a simple client-server application, where client receives some information about a user and writes it into a file.
The first time running it after compilation goes fine, but when I run it a second time without recompiling it the client won't connect to the server.
That would be great if anyone could help me.
Thank's in advance.

Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 9004

struct user_t
{
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    int id;
};

int main()
{
    int choice = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int server_fd, new_socket;
    struct user_t user;
    pid_t pid;

    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    listen(server_fd, 1);

    new_socket = accept(server_fd, NULL, NULL);

    while (choice)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid > 0)
            wait(NULL);
        else
            break;
        printf("Enter 1 to add one more user, 0 to exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        send(new_socket,&choice, sizeof(choice), 0);
        if (!choice)
        {
            close(new_socket);
            shutdown(server_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter user's name\n");
    scanf("%s", user.name);
    printf("Enter user's surname\n");
    scanf("%s", user.surname);
    printf("Enter user's age\n");
    scanf("%d", &user.age);
    printf("Enter user's id\n");
    scanf("%d", &user.id);

    send(new_socket, user.name, sizeof(user.name), 0);
    send(new_socket, user.surname, sizeof(user.surname), 0);
    send(new_socket, &user.age, sizeof(user.age), 0);
    send(new_socket, &user.id, sizeof(user.id), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 9004

struct user_t
{
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    int id;
};

int main()
{
    int connection = 1;
    FILE* fptr;
    int choice = 1, size;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int network_socket;
    pid_t pid;
    struct user_t user;

    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    while (connection != 0)
    {
        connection = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    }

    fptr = fopen("user", "w");
    while (choice)
    {

        if(recv(network_socket, user.name, sizeof(user.name), 0) > 0)
            fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", user.name);
        if(recv(network_socket, user.surname, sizeof(user.surname), 0) > 0)
            fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", user.surname);        
        if(recv(network_socket, &user.age, sizeof(user.age), 0) > 0)
            fprintf(fptr, "%d\n", user.age);
        if(recv(network_socket, &user.id, sizeof(user.id), 0) > 0)
            fprintf(fptr, "%d\n\n", user.id);
        if(recv(network_socket, &choice, sizeof(choice), 0) > 0)
            fprintf(fptr, "%d", choice);
    }

    close(network_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're setting `address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY`.... which isn't a valid IP address.  I'm surprised `connect()` ever succeeds at all.  You need to set it to `htonl(a)` where a is the IP address of your server (or 127.0.0.1)

Comment: "but when I run it a second time without recompiling" What is "it"? Which program do you have to rebuild? The server? The client? Both programs? If it is the server only, the port is probably still busy.

Comment: This has nothing to do with recompiling. You need to set the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option to bind to the same port shortly after shutting down the server. Recompling is just a coincidence, because it delays starting the server until after the port times out.

Comment: In the server, I'd do the `SO_REUSEADDR` just before the `bind`. I'd put the `accept` inside the loop. And, AFAIK, you can't do `shutdown` on `server_fd` as it will return an error because `listen` does _not_ do a connect that can be shut down